# I am getting an error while creating In-App Purchases. How is the Solution?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, store

While my in-app purchases are ready, "To submit an app with the Magazines and Newspapers category, you must offer at least one auto-renewable subscription. Create one in In-App Purchases."  I am getting your error.My goal is to publish free Apps but the store pushes me to create a purchase. In the automatic mail I received, I asked Application presents content in Newsstand yes, but it still gives the same error. Please help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF8CK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKb2H.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M5Mt.png)

Comment: You haven't created an *auto renewing subscription* IAP as per the error message. Alternatively don't list your app in the magazines and newspapers category.

Comment: There are 2 IAPs as seen in the pictures. I did not choose the magazine and newspaper category, but the system says this. My category is different.

Comment: You answered "yes" to "Application presents content in newsstand". Neither of your IAPs are auto renewing subscription. You have a non consumable and a non renewing subscription.

Comment: because if I didn't, I couldn't send my application. The post is as follows: We have detected one or more issues for your app called "Get Erciyesden" posted on a recent App Store review 1.2 (3). Please fix the issues below and install again.

Comment: ITMS-90138: Your Info.plist contains the sub property UINewsstandIcon under CFBundleIcons, intended for use with Newstand properties. To add newsstand properties, Info.plist must contain the key UINewsstandApp = true Info.plist.

Comment: Delete the newsstand icon and remove the `UINewsstandApp = true` key.

Comment: Although auto renewed subscription writes missing metadata is correct.

Comment: 1.0 Invalid Binary is writing now

Comment: Same mail came again

Comment: Did you remove the newsstand icon key from your info.plist?

Comment: yes I did. I uninstalled and installed as you said. and mail says the same thing again.

Comment: It says that you still have `UINewstandIcon` under `CFBundleIcons` in your `info.plist`?  Then you probably do. Export your ipa to your local machine rather than uploading it directly to Apple and look inside (it is just a zip file; you can change the extension to .zip) examine the included info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply choose another category that still fits the description of your app. There is no way to get around this if you don't have a subscription API setup.

Comment: that's not my category anyway. actually my category is food and drink. it says the same thing if I choose another.

Comment: Then it must have something to do with your info.plist -- make sure UINewsstandApp is set to false.

Comment: I said no and removed it. but the mail came. ITMS-90138: Your Info.plist contains the sub property UINewsstandIcon under

Comment: CFBundleIcons, intended for use with Newstand properties. To add newsstand properties, Info.plist must contain the key UINewsstandApp = true Info.plist.